# I need a script to change screen resolution in Linux Mint 15 then launch an application

Tags: linux, screen, resolution, linux-mint

Probably a simple question with a simple answer.
I have an application that will sometimes crash and cause my screen resolution to change when it does. For the moment I just want to have a quick script I can run that will change my screen resolution back where it's supposed to be then re-launch the app.

I'm running Linux Mint 15 KDE 64 bit and my default screen is 1600x900.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not listed what you have tried, if anything, thus far.  However since you are running Mint, you probably have xrandr or can easily get it.

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 164mm
1366x768       60.0*+
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9
```

Then you just user xrandr -s to change the screen resolution mode.  So say I wanted to change to change to 1024x768 I would just run:

```
xrandr -s 2
```

Here is a really simple script to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am going to check the screen resolution"
xrandr -q
sleep 5s
echo "I am going to change the screen resolution to 1024x768"
xrandr -s 2
echo "Now we are going to to check the resolution again"
xrandr -q
sleep 5s
echo "Now I am going to change the resolution back to 1366x768"
xrandr -s 0
echo "Now we check yet again"
xrandr -q
sleep 5s
```

If I am misinterpreting what you are asking for then please update your question to better reflect your aim.

Comment: I subsequently found I can bring up lxrandr with a script which lets me choose the reso from the application then launches the script but how would I code the script to just automatically run the resolution I want?

Comment: I am confused on why you are using lxrandr to set the resolution in a script instead of just xrandr, but maybe I am not fully understanding your question.  I will include a really simple script in my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: I think you've actually given me two ways to accomplish what I want. Which is perfect. Thanks for taking the time to help me! Jeff

Comment: No problem.  Just mark the answer as correct if you appreciate the help ;).  Thank you.